# reRender is not working

Tags: apex, visualforce, rerender, rendered

i write a simple visualforce page

```
<apex:page controller="Sample1">
  <!-- Begin Default Content REMOVE THIS -->
  <h1>Congratulations</h1>
  This is your new Page
  <apex:outputText id="outText"value="Hello World" rendered= "{! xx}"/>
  <apex:form>
  <apex:commandButton value="Click" action="{!changeValue}" rerender="outText"/>
  </apex:form>
  <!-- End Default Content REMOVE THIS -->
</apex:page>
```

and controller code is

```
public class Sample1{
public Boolean xx{get;set;}
public Sample1(){
xx=true;
}

public PageReference changeValue(){
xx=false;
return null;
}
}
```

but when i click the button nothing happens Hello World still renders.Please explain why rerender is not working ??

Answer (score 2):

The element that you re-render seems to have to be a container of the outputText; this works:

```
<apex:page controller="Sample1">
  <apex:outputPanel layout="block" id="outText">
      <apex:outputText value="Hello World" rendered= "{!xx}"/>
  </apex:outputPanel>
  <apex:form>
      <apex:commandButton value="Click" action="{!changeValue}" rerender="outText"/>
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

The "Bob Buzzard Blog" post [Visualforce Re-rendering Woes](http://bobbuzzard.blogspot.ie/2011/02/visualforce-re-rendering-woes.html) suggests the reasoning behing this design:

> ... containing output panel will always be present on the page and
>   thus the Ajax request will be able to update it on completion. The
>   inner component may or may not be rendered depending on ...