# Which elements get rerendered and which can't be

Tags: visualforce, rerender, rendered, pageblock

i previously asked a question [reRender is not working](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/41241/rerender-is-not-working) .i get a good reply of that .again i am trying to rerender a pageBlock and its not getting rerendered.i want to know which elements get rerendered and which can't be and also please guidleine how to make this page block rerendered

```
<apex:page standardController="Lead" extensions="PopupController" sidebar="false" showHeader="false" title="Request to Change">
<apex:includeScript value="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js" />
<apex:form>
<apex:pageBlock id="theform" rendered="{! req.Id == null}">
<apex:pageBlockButtons location="bottom">
<apex:commandButton value="Submit" action="{!save}" onclick="callParent(this);" id="submit" rerender="theform,outText"/>
<apex:commandButton value="Cancel" id="cancel"/>
</apex:pageBlockButtons>
<apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
  <apex:outputField label="Lead :" value="{!Lead.Name}"/>
  <apex:inputField label="Assign To Partner :" value="{! req.PartnerUserId__c}" />
</apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageBlock>
  </apex:form>
  <script type="text/javascript">

  function callParent(){
   document.domain =document.domain;
    parent.postMessage('closeModal','*');   
    return true;
  }

  </script>
  <apex:outputPanel id="outText">
  <apex:outputText value="Your request successfully submitted" rendered="{! req.Id != null}" />
</apex:outputPanel>
</apex:page>
```

in starting req.Id is null

Comment: A couple of things stand out here that may or may not be the issue. 1) If there is a Javascript error in `callParent` it could prevent the form submission. 2) The standard controllers Save action is being called, which I think will usually redirect via a PageReference. Are you seeing any Javascript errors or page redirections. In what way are the page blocks not re-rendering?

Comment: after save page block should disappear because req.Id after save is not null .i can see outputtext in  page with pageblock but page block should disappear.

Answer (score 1):

So the contents of the `outText` outputPanel is being rerendered, but the `theform` pageBlock is not?

Try moving the contents to be rendered dynamically within the component. E.g. wrap the whole thing in an outputPanel that has the Id to be rerendered, then check the value of req.Id within that. Alternatively, you might be able to put `id="theform"` on the apex:form tag instead.

E.g.

```
<apex:form>
    <apex:outputPanel id="theform">
        <apex:pageBlock  rendered="{! req.Id == null}">
            <apex:pageBlockButtons location="bottom">
                <apex:commandButton value="Submit" action="{!save}" onclick="callParent(this);" id="submit" rerender="theform,outText"/>
                <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" id="cancel"/>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
                <apex:outputField label="Lead :" value="{!Lead.Name}"/>
                <apex:inputField label="Assign To Partner :" value="{! req.PartnerUserId__c}" />
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:outputPanel>
</apex:form>
```